# Cannot insert to SQL Server CE with autoincrement

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I am unable to insert new row to a SQL Server CE 3.5 table due to an auto-increment column

My schema is as simple as:

```
@"CREATE TABLE DataTable ("Foo_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, " +
                          "FooName NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)
```

And my insert statement in C#

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES(@Foo_ID, @FooName)", con))
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("FooName", "test123"));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then I get the error:

> *System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlCeParameter with ParameterName
>   'Foo_ID' is not contained by this SqlCeParameterCollection*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your column `FOO_ID` is an auto-increment `IDENTITY` column, you must omit it from your  `INSERT` statement. As such, you need to **explicitly** specify the list of columns you want to insert values into - try this:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO DataTable(FooName) VALUES(@FooName)", con))
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("FooName", "test123"));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have `@Foo_ID` as a query in your parameter, but don't add such a parameter with `cmd.Parameters.Add`.

Comment: if its an autoincrement field, you dont need to call it in the statement: `SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES(@FooName, con))
`

Comment: Specifying `@Foo_ID` means you intend to supply a parameter named `Foo_ID`.  If you tell it that, it will complain that you haven't supplied a value for it.  Therefore - don't say you'll include one :)  `INSERT INTO DataTable (FooName) VALUES (@FooName)`

Answer (score -1):

Try sending -1 as the ID, that way it will force the autoincrement to set the correct value.